# Azure IOT Device client method CompleteFileUploadAsync giving error 403 as forbidden when IsSuccess = true, works for IsSuccess = false

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

I have enabled private endpoint for iot hub and azure storage account and restricted the public traffic, when i am uploading a file it gets uploaded successfully but when calling CompleteFileUploadAsync method of device client i am getting error 403 as forbidden. But when passing the IsSuccess = false its working with current configuration, i changed the Allow access from to "All networks" then its working.

I want to make sure that its notifying within private network when file uploaded successfully as its working when file upload fails.

Code:

```
private static async Task SendToBlobAsync(DeviceClient deviceClient, string fileName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Uploading file: {0}", fileName);
            var watch = System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch.StartNew();

           var sas =  await deviceClient.GetFileUploadSasUriAsync(new FileUploadSasUriRequest { BlobName = fileName });
            var blob = new CloudBlockBlob(sas.GetBlobUri());
            await blob.UploadFromFileAsync(fileName);
            await deviceClient.CompleteFileUploadAsync(new FileUploadCompletionNotification { CorrelationId = sas.CorrelationId, IsSuccess = true });

            watch.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine("Time to upload file: {0}ms\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
        }
```

The method throwing the below error message :

```
{
   "Message":"{\"errorCode\":400020,\"trackingId\":\"72f35ff2b08f4312bc0e9f9d36be1061-G:0-TimeStamp:02/23/2021 14:24:46\",\"message\":\"BadRequest\",\"timestampUtc\":\"2021-02-23T14:24:46.3420546Z\"}",
   "ExceptionMessage":"ErrorCode: InvalidStorageEndpointOrBlob\r\nMessage: Storage endpoint '$default' or blob name device001/image.jpg is invalid\r\nTimestamp: 02/23/2021 14:24:46\r\nTracking ID: 72f35ff2b08f4312bc0e9f9d36be1061-G:0-TimeStamp:02/23/2021 14:24:46\r\nPublic Message: \r\nPublic Info: null\r\nException: Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Core.Exceptions.IotHubException: Storage endpoint '$default' or blob name device001/image.jpg is invalid ---> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.<>c__DisplayClass22.<FetchAttributesImpl>b__21(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__5(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Runtime.FileUpload.IotHubFileUploadManager.<GenerateFileUploadNotificationAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\runtime\\FileUpload\\IotHubFileUploadManager.cs:line 153\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Runtime.FileUpload.IotHubFileUploadManager.<GenerateFileUploadNotificationAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\runtime\\FileUpload\\IotHubFileUploadManager.cs:line 180\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Runtime.Http.HttpRuntimeProvider.<UpdateAndNotifyFileUploadStatusAsync>d__41.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\runtime\\Http\\HttpRuntimeProvider.cs:line 1215\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Runtime.Http.HttpRuntimeActionResult`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\mgmt\\Http\\HttpRuntimeActionResult.cs:line 153\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Management.ActionFilters.GlobalActionFilter.<ExecuteActionFilterAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\mgmt\\ActionFilters\\GlobalActionFilter.cs:line 42\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()",
   "ExceptionType":"Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Common.Core.Exceptions.IotHubException",
   "StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Runtime.FileUpload.IotHubFileUploadManager.<GenerateFileUploadNotificationAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\runtime\\FileUpload\\IotHubFileUploadManager.cs:line 180\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Runtime.Http.HttpRuntimeProvider.<UpdateAndNotifyFileUploadStatusAsync>d__41.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\runtime\\Http\\HttpRuntimeProvider.cs:line 1215\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Runtime.Http.HttpRuntimeActionResult`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__7.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\mgmt\\Http\\HttpRuntimeActionResult.cs:line 153\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Management.ActionFilters.GlobalActionFilter.<ExecuteActionFilterAsync>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\mgmt\\ActionFilters\\GlobalActionFilter.cs:line 42\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()",
   "InnerException":{
      "Message":"An error has occurred.",
      "ExceptionMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.",
      "ExceptionType":"Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException",
      "StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndExecuteAsync[T](IAsyncResult result)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Util.AsyncExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7.<CreateCallbackVoid>b__5(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Gateway.Runtime.FileUpload.IotHubFileUploadManager.<GenerateFileUploadNotificationAsync>d__10.MoveNext() in C:\\source\\gateway\\runtime\\FileUpload\\IotHubFileUploadManager.cs:line 153",
      "InnerException":{
         "Message":"An error has occurred.",
         "ExceptionMessage":"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.",
         "ExceptionType":"System.Net.WebException",
         "StackTrace":"   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Shared.Protocol.HttpResponseParsers.ProcessExpectedStatusCodeNoException[T](HttpStatusCode expectedStatusCode, HttpStatusCode actualStatusCode, T retVal, StorageCommandBase`1 cmd, Exception ex)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.<>c__DisplayClass22.<FetchAttributesImpl>b__21(RESTCommand`1 cmd, HttpWebResponse resp, Exception ex, OperationContext ctx)\r\n   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.EndGetResponse[T](IAsyncResult getResponseResult)"
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: hi, it seems this error message is in JSON. could you please format it as such, and replace `\r\n` with actual newlines? it's quite hard to read at the moment. cheers

Comment: I'm running into a similar issue with the Java sdk